# how to make a webhook in python to communicate with the meta API and receive messages from wpp

Tags: python, api, flask, ngrok

I'm trying to develop an application for whatsapp business using meta's graph API, but it's impossible to connect the API with my webhook. In order to simply do some tests I'm using Ngrok to create a tunnel, and the python flask library to create the webhook, here's the code:

`

```
`from flask import Flask, request
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)

TOKEN = '...'

def send_message(number, message):
    url = 'https://api.metasmart.com.br/v1/whatsapp/send_message'
    data = {
        'phone': number,
        'message': message
    }
    headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {TOKEN}',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print('Mensagem enviada com sucesso!')
    else:
        print('Erro ao enviar mensagem: ', response.content)

#@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
@app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST'])
def webhook():
    # O token de verificação que você escolher na API do Meta
    expected_token = 'sleep'

    # Verificar se o token recebido é o mesmo que o token esperado
    if request.args.get('token') != expected_token:
        return '', 403

    data = request.json
    if data['event'] == 'incoming_message':
        message = data['message']
        sender = data['from']
        print(f'Mensagem recebida de {sender}: {message}')
        # Enviar uma resposta de exemplo
        reply = f'Você disse: {message}'
        send_message(sender, reply)
    return '', 200


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()`
```

`

I tried using ngrok as a tunnel to connect the local webhook to the meta api, I just want to print the received messages.

Comment: PM from ngrok here. I'm curious what error you are seeing and if you think it's from your code or from ngrok.

Comment: I don't think that is a problem with ngrok, but maybe it is because i don't use a TLS certificate. The error: "405 METHOD NOT ALLOWED "